# How to access an outside object inside foreach in javascript

Tags: javascript

I get undefined when trying to access an object while iterating through an array.

```
obj={
"field":"value"
};

var arr=[values];

console.log(obj.entry);//works

arr.forEach(function(entry) {
console.log(entry); //works
console.log(obj.entry); //undefined
});
```

Comment: `console.log(obj.entry);` here it will give you undefined

Comment: how come `console.log(obj.entry);` works as there is no `entry` property? Seems you are looking for `console.log(obj[entry]);`

Comment: I named it entry 'console.log(obj.entry);' just to show that the particular entry value from foreach exists in the object. Sorry if it was confusing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use square brackets while accessing object key through a variable

```js
obj = {
  "field": "value"
};

var arr = ["field", "field2", "field3"];
arr.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log(obj[entry]); //value
});
```

Comment: Should you not look for a dupe instead?